# How to get the value mapping of a Chrome local storage result through an argument?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a function:

```
            //  Get the value out of Chrome local storage
        chrome.storage.local.get(sourcePath, function(result) {
                //  Test the result
            alert(JSON.stringify(result.sourcePath));
            });
```

And a call to check it:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'userAcceptanceAgreement': true});
```

Right now, I would like to know how to get my function, when called with the above argument, to pass that value into the `result.sourcePath` alert.  As is, it shows `result` with the correct storage value of `{'userAcceptanceAgreement': true}`, but `result.sourcePath` comes up as undefined because it isn't trying to locate the key:value pair for the argument, but for a literal `sourcePath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Basic JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) here.

```
var sourcePath = 'userAcceptanceAgreement';
result.sourcePath; // Accesses literally "sourcePath"
result[sourcePath]; // Accesses "userAcceptanceAgreement"
```

*Note that you buried the problem under a lot of noise. Please consider constructing a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time.*